# Who has the highest bounty in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

I'd like to know, who in the *One Piece* world has the max bounty declared against them till date? Note that the bounty amount has to be mentioned in either anime or manga or in the movies. I am assuming it is Katakuri? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The current highest active bounty is that of Charlotte Katakuri, one of the Three Sweet Commanders of Yonko Big Mom with a bounty of 1,057,000,000.

Taken from [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bounties). One Piece Manga — Vol. 86 Chapter 860 (p. 14) is given as reference.

Comment: But I am very sure that Dragon is the most wanted man. Though not mentioned as a value, Garp and Robin said that he has the biggest bounty out there.

Comment: At what point in the manga/story did they say that? Maybe it is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

As of chapter 957 "Ultimate" we now know that the highest bounty ever given so far is **[image] 5,564,800,000**, the bounty of the Pirate king Gol D. Roger.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Monkey D Luffy has the highest known bounty of **[image] 1,500,000,000** (1.5 billion Beri)

[image]

Comment: true lol but then what about the bounties of the yonko?

Comment: Well, the Yonko would have higher bounties. But it's not revealed yet. But mainly, who would have the guts to defeat a Yonko and if successful, claim the bounty from the Government, all while showing they're as much as a threat the Yonko was?

Comment: lmaoo you do have a point there, but like I dont get why the Yonkos bounties are unknown, cause like one would think that the Most logical thing would be to pressure and capture all Yonkos since they have the a lot of powers and followers

Comment: The reason there are three divisions of power; World Govt, Shichibukai and Yonko, is because of their massive power. Hence the reason to why the Govt cant take them down. Each Yonko is as powerful as the Government.